# mySQL unsigned float returning out of range error when not supposed to

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, unsigned

Why is my unsigned float column returning error saying `"Out of range value for column amount "` when I try to do a PUT query, updating the amount value from `999` to be `999 = 999 - 998`

**Query**

```
if(req.body.transaction_type === 'credit'){
    sql_query = `UPDATE currency SET amount = amount - ${req.body.transaction_amount}`;
}
```

**SQL Table**

[image]
[image]

**Error**
[image]

Comment: What value does `req.body.transaction_amount` have? You should also consider using placeholders instead of concatenating SQL commands, which is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen 998. Apparently when i have a double digit value like 99 in my amount column and i try to alter the table to add unsigned to the amount column it also shows the same error message saying out of range